# Setting node pointer to null

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

First of all. I appreciate the help guys!

This is the problem.Trying to set one of list's edges to null

```
list[i].getAttachedNode(j) = 0;
```

This is the error.

```
Prj3.cpp:165:34: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

This is my list decleration.

```
Node list[47];
```

This is the attachedNode implementation.

```
Node* Node::getAttachedNode(int direction) {return attachedNode[direction];}
```

[b]Here is the block its contained in.

```
for(int i = 0; i<48; i++)
      {
        for(int j = 0; j<6; j++)
        {  
        string info = g.returnInfo(i,j);

            switch(j)
                {
            case 0:
            list[i].setNodeName(info);
            break;
            case 1:
            if(info.compare(null) == 0)
            {list[i].getAttachedNode(j) = 0;}
            break;
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should return a `Node*&`.

Comment: let me see the declaration of list

Comment: @SethCarnegie: You should make that an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty clear:

```
list[i].getAttachedNode(j)
```

is an r-value, so it can't be assigned to. Just have `getAttachedNode` return a reference:

```
Node*& Node::getAttachedNode(int direction) {return attachedNode[direction];}
```

Comment: Thank you this fixed it. Would you mind explaining this to me a little? Im a bit fussy on my visualization of this. Like, Node* returns the memory address. So Node*& returns the actual node pointer? Is that correct.

Comment: @TheNodeCommode: Returning `Node*` says "take this pointer and give a copy to the caller".  Then you try to modify the copy which wasn't what you wanted to do.  Returning `Node*&' says "take this pointer and give it to the caller".  Then you can successfully change it.

Comment: Ah, ok. But I will also need to use getAttachedNode() to link to another object not just null. When I do that I will need to take it by reference as well and assign it to a copy(Node*) of the address of some object.Is that correct?